# How to redirect to spring controller method in app deployed on local server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, redirect

On my local Tomcat server I develop few projects. One of them I write in Spring MVC. I want to redirect some request to another method of controller. I know that it's possible by use: `return "redirect:/path/to/resource";` but if I have deployed app on Tomcat I have to use prefix like: `return "redirect:`**`/appname`**`/path/to/resource";`. 
How to make it work on server with prefix and without?

Comment: It sounds like you want to redirect the user to a controller method in a different application that is deployed to the same Tomcat instance, is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to redirect user to the same application but without adding **"/appname"** in all redirections because on target server those prefix won't exist.

Comment: So you're redirecting to the same app on a different server where the app is running as the ROOT context?

Comment: No, I want to redirect to the same app on the same server but I don't want to change every path in case moving app to other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're having trouble because you've got the app running as the root context in some environments and not in others.  You can use the methods available on the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects to do a redirect that is more environment independent.  An example Spring controller method would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public void test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String url = request.getScheme() + "://" + 
                 request.getServerName() + ":" + 
                 request.getServerPort() + 
                 request.getContextPath() + "/path/to/resource";
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

The `getContextPath` part in particular solves the problem you're talking about, it will just return `/` if the app is running as the root context but will return `/appname` if the app is running as `appname` like in your example.

Comment: Thanks! It's solution.